# INPUT auto fill rest of container width

Tags: html, css

I'm looking for the trick to expand my input field to all avaliable space of container but not over folowing element.
I prepared [example](http://jsbin.com/egiveb/13/edit) witch looks ok in chrome only. FF looks quite ok, but no result in IE.

I have container DIV with INPUT and text (SPAN) in one line. Text can be changed (e.g. translated) so i do not know text width. In my example i used `display: table-cell`, please look my [example](http://jsbin.com/egiveb/13/edit).

```
+----container---------------------------+
|+---input----------------++--text------+|
||                        ||            ||
|+------------------------++------------+|
+----------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made this from complete scratch

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/gYkMe/)

```
<div class="container">
    <label>Demo</label>
    <span><input type="text" /></span>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#container {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}

label, span {
    display: table-cell;
}

span {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 5px;
}

input {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: looks good, but i need to check this on IE9 - this is my target.

Comment: @Saram Works, I've checked using developers mode as am using IE10

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/gYkMe/9/ - i changed order for my requirements. I'll accept aswer as soon as i verify it :)

Comment: Tested. Works on IE9. Thanx.